# remote wipe windows computer

Tags: windows, security, remote-control

Is there a way to wipe the hard drives of a windows machine remotely? like the remote wipe function that's built into iOS. I can still use remote desktop to access (with admin rights) the machine, so I can install any program.

Comment: why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not wipe down system drive, obviously...

If you have remote desktop connection as admin to the machine than you can wipe down non-system drives.

Comment: is there a way to overwrite the free space in the system drive with zeros?

Comment: Yes. You can do that. Various security related programs will do the trick. Depends on what OS are you running. For Windows there is [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/)

Comment: Why is it obvious that the system drive can not be wiped down?

Comment: If by wiping down a hardrive/partition we consider removing all the data from it than I guess it is hardly possible to accomplish such an operation on the system partition which is currently loaded especially on Windows. Of course one can do ssh root@host, rm -rf --no-preserve-root / but at some point rm will remove enough files for system to crash. At this point there should be files still remaining there, thus operation of wiping down a hard drive would be left incomplete. Am I wrong on this point?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 and Server 2012 R2 will have this feature, it however will only remove specific information, documents, e-mails, but not the whole OS.